# attaching pictures to an email being sent using java mail API

Tags: java, api, email

i have a method that i use to send an email using java. i would like to know how to attach a picture to the top of the email? i tried using MimeMessageParts or something and i couldnt get it to work? i would like to be able to pass a BufferedImage into the method as a parameter and have it attach it to the top.. any help would be appreciated :)

```
public static void Send(final String username, final String password, 
    String recipientEmail, String ccEmail, String title, String message) 
    throws AddressException, MessagingException 
{

Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";

// Get a Properties object
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("mail.smtps.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true");


props.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

// -- Create a new message --
final MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

// -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username + "@gmail.com"));
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipientEmail, false));

if (ccEmail.length() > 0) {
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(ccEmail, false));
}

msg.setSubject(title);
msg.setText(message, "utf-8");
msg.setSentDate(new Date());

SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport)session.getTransport("smtps");

t.connect("smtp.gmail.com", username, password);
t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());      
t.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For attachment you need to create separate `MimeBodyPart`, Here is sample code,

   ```
   MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
   FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource(filename) {
     @Override
    public String getContentType() {
         return "application/octet-stream";
           }
   };
   attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDataSource));
   ```
2. For mail text you need another `MimeBodyPart`

   ```
   MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
   messagePart.setText(bodyText);
   ```
3. Combine these two `MimeBodyPart` into `Multipart`

   ```
   Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
   multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart);
   multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
   ```
4. At last, send the email

   ```
    ...........
    final MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 
    msg.setContent(multipart);
    Transport.send(msg);
   ```

For details, see this [link](http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-send-an-email-with-attachment/).